# How do you enable tool when clicking on a Location in a List in Dashboard, the map zooms to that location?

Tags: operations-dashboard

I have created a Dashboard that contain Geo-Coded broken Water main locations in a list that shows on the dashboard.  I would like to be able to choose the record in the list and have the map zoom to that Location.

Is there a configuration I am missing or does some code need to be written?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

Indeed you can. It is in the Configure of the List.
Configure > Actions tab > Add Action > Zoom > Add Target > Map

You can also trigger the popup, flash the icon, etc.

[image: List Actions]